# Como hacer un if en Javascript según API

Tags: javascript

*En un post vi que esto es para obtener la ip del usuario:*

```
<script>
     $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        });
</script>
```

Y que devuelve esto:

```
{
  "ip": "116.12.250.1",
  "country_code": "SG",
  "country_name": "Singapore",
  "region_code": "01",
  "region_name": "Central Singapore Community Development Council",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "zip_code": "",
  "time_zone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "latitude": 1.2931,
  "longitude": 103.8558,
  "metro_code": 0
}
```

***Hasta ahí todo bien, pero como hago un if si su country_code es por ejemplo 'SG' ?***

Comment: `IF` para validar que sea `SG` ?  qué desea realizar si es `SG` ? , para obtener el `country_code` se accede  `data.country_code`   con ese valor se puede validar y/o realizar acciones como por ejemplo el  `if(data.country_code == 'SG'){...}`

Comment: eso intenté: Uncaught ReferenceError: country_code is not defined

Comment: Eduardo primero se accede al `array` **data** y luego a su propiedad , `if(data.country_code == 'SG'){...}` , agregue que intentó a su pregunta.

Comment: gracias ! soy novato, estoy aprendiendo javascript y demás , podrias ponerle como respuesta? me sirvio :)

Comment: Una pregunta, como hago el if , si está fuera de la funcion del GET?

Comment: Para hacerlo por fuera del llamado Get, tendrías que utilizar un callback, es decir, invocar una función que recibe por parámetro los datos del api y hace lo que deba hacer con esos datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el siguiente link puede [conocer como funciona el if else](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/if...else)

```
// Ejemplo

if ( expresion ) {
    // hacer algo si expresion es verdadera
} else {
    // de lo contrario hacer otra cosa
}
```

Segun el codigo que haz dado, puedes usar el `if else` como sigue:

```js
data = {
  "ip": "116.12.250.1",
  "country_code": "SG",
  "country_name": "Singapore",
  "region_code": "01",
  "region_name": "Central Singapore Community Development Council",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "zip_code": "",
  "time_zone": "Asia/Singapore",
  "latitude": 1.2931,
  "longitude": 103.8558,
  "metro_code": 0
}

if (data.country_code == "SG") {
 console.log("country es SG!");
} else {
 console.log("country NO es SG!");
}
```

```js
var data = ""; // variable global
$.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(j) {
 data = j;
 document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].disabled ="";
});

function displayData() {
 console.log(data);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="displayData()" disabled>display Data</button>
```

Comment: si eso  es obvio, pero es usar el if else fuera de la función aunque no pregunté eso primeramente... gracias :)

Comment: debes crear una variable global y guardar los datos en dicha variable, te he dejado un ejemplo.

Comment: Eso intenté , veelo tu mismo en tu codigo 'data is not defined' ( añadiendo jquery)

Comment: `$.getJSON` es asyncrono por lo que deberás primero esperar a que cargue el JSON para poder trabajar con el, he agregado un seTimeout() al ejemplo y ahora si despliega el JSON, Saludos!! ;))...

Comment: He colocado un **botón** que al pulsarlo te muestra `data`.

Comment: como funciona lo del boton? fwBasic?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58277/discussion-between-fwbasic-and-eduardo-sebastian).